# Paypal Express Checkout button not showing

Tags: paypal, paypal-express, magento1.9.0.1

I have been searching how to use Paypal Express Checkout, but i can't show the Paypal button on my products page or even in the cart page...

As you can see below, i have the following configuration on my admin page:
[image: Magento Admin Configuration for Paypal Express]

What else do i need to do for this to properly work?

PS: I already have read the paypal guides and it just confused me more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i've been talking with Paypal support team, and it turns out it was problem with the template i was using. After that, I've made a ticket with the theme support team and they solved the problem for me.

The problem was in a comment in paypal.xml in my theme, so if someone have the same problem just look at

```
/public_html/app/design/frontend/package_name/theme_name/layout/paypal.xml
```

and see if there is something commented.

PS: Don't forget to disable Magento Cache

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Admin -> System -> Cache Management` and click `Flush Magento Cache`.

Comment: Thanks, but i already cleaned all Caches and it still doesn't show.. I'm using Sahara template from Theme Forest, could it be a problem with the template?

Answer (score 1):

Please check your settings in

```
System->Configuration->Advanced
```

Are the modules:

```
Mage_Payment 
Mage_Paypal
```

have the status **"Enabled"**?

Comment: I already solved the problem, in contact with the support team of my theme. I gave my solution to this problem in an awnser early, but thanks for your support anyway! :)